# Pass parameters to notebook being opened?

Tags: scripting, .netlink

Is there a way to pass a parameter to a notebook which is being programmatically opened?

For example, I would like to be able to pass a parameter to **myNotebook.nb**

```
Process.Start("myNotebook.nb")
```

I am aware it could be done with scripting, but the aim is to have this notebook auto-execute with some parameter information.

An example use case is: a flight number link could appear on a webpage or a Word document, which when clicked would open a world map notebook and show the flight path.  The notebook would just need the flight number.  (The weblink or Word-link might open the map notebook via a registry entry.)

Comment: The notebook could read environmental variables, registries, files, servers and more. What are the constraints?

Comment: @rhermans I did consider reading the parameters from somewhere once the notebook is open and running but it would be more versatile to pass the parameter(s) with the launch command.  (No need to place the info somethere beforehand.)

Comment: Have you tried wolframscript? You can pass arguments to a script. I assume that the script itself can then open the notebook and use those arguments to inject something. I've never done this, just brainstorming.

Comment: @lericr Yes, I'm hoping to avoid the two step process of opening a kernel that opens a notebook (with its own kernel).

Comment: Maybe `NotebookTemplate`?

Comment: But I guess you'd still need a kernel to do `GenerateDocument` or whatever.

Comment: Sorry, just read the example use case... could this be an API instead of a local notebook?

Comment: @lericr At the moment I'd just like to use the desktop Mathematica licence.

Comment: Hmm. What about having having your button copy the data to the clipboard and then have an initialization cell that accesses the clipboard, e.g. `Paste`?

Comment: @lericr Interesting idea